# Asana API error - unsupported browser when using an ios client

Tags: objective-c, ios, asana

I am sending an API call to Asana from an iOS client and am getting an HTML page with the title: Asana - Unsupported Browser which tells me something is wrong with the way I make the call.

My API calling code is as follows:

Client Settings are here:

```
- (id) initHTTPClient {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ASANA_BASE_URL]];

    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:ASANA_API_KEY password:[NSString string]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

API call is constructed here:

```
- (void) getCurrentUser {

    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionary];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/users/me.json" parameters:parameters];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Success, here's what we got: %@",response);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure, error: %@",error.debugDescription);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: You're probably accessing the wrong URL. Can you provide the value of the ASANA_BASE_URL constant you are using?

Comment: That was indeed the case, updating it to `@"https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/"` worked. Thanks.